# Confgure nginx as reverse proxy for wildfly web applications

Tags: java, nginx, wildfly

I have a webapp deployed on a wildfly 10.1 application server.
This webapp is listened on: http://localhost:8080/app-profile-jsp/ (1)

I successful installed nginx. The server is successfull installed and I test to serve static web pages and images.

Now I want configure nginx to acccess the web app from
"http://www.frizio.local" (2) url.
I configure this address in /etc/hosts.

My configuration in nginx is the following:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     frizio.local www.frizio.local;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/static.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/static.error.log;

    root /srv/http/static;


    location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/app-profile-jsp;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    }


    location /pics {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
    }
}
```

When I try to access to (2) the server respond "404 not found".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed the trailing / of the proxypass :

```
proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/app-profile-jsp/;
```

An other thing, I don't think you need the `proxy_redirect off;` here.

Hope it helped !

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Another newbie question: I think that there is a problem with redirect, to manage the pages that my wildfly webapp contains. I have an error "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" .. I suppose that i would add $request_uri in some rows in configuration file. Didn't it? Where?

Comment: Did you tried to do just that: 
    `location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/app-profile-jsp/;
    }`
No redirect, upstream... just the proxy_pass.